# How to print tables in different pages at a time using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have requirement to print html tables in different pages at a time. All these tables are inside the same division.Each page of the print should only have a single table next table should come at next page.
[this is my demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/8u9r4xnb/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="divTimeTables"><table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>table1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><table id="tblTeacherTimeTable1"><thead><tr><th>TeacherName</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Monday</td><td>class&Sub2</td><td>class&Sub2</td><td>class&Sub2</td><td>class&Sub2</td><td>class&Sub2</td></tr><tr><td>Tuesday</td><td>class&Sub2</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr></tbody><tr><td>WednessDay</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr><tr><td>Thursday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr><tr><td>Friday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr><tr><td>Friday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr></table></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>table2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><table id="tblTeacherTimeTable2"><thead><tr><th>TeacherName</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Monday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr><tr><td>Tuesday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr></tbody><tr><td>WednessDay</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr><tr><td>Thursday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr><tr><td>Friday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr><tr><td>Friday</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td><td>class&Sub</td></tr></table></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>

    </table></div>
<button id="btnPrint">Print</button>
```

Comment: and your javascript?

Answer (score 1):

If your using CSS print you can just add
 at the bottom of your first table or anywhere you would like to set a page-break. (just an option thought)

```
@media print {
    .page-break {page-break-after: initial;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media querys

```
    <section>
<table id="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>table1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="tblTeacherTimeTable1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>TeacherName</th>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>3</th>
                            <th>4</th>
                            <th>5</th>
                            <th>6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Monday</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tuesday</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>WednessDay</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thursday</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Friday</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Friday</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </section>
<section>
<table id="table2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>table2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="tblTeacherTimeTable2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>TeacherName</th>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>3</th>
                            <th>4</th>
                            <th>5</th>
                            <th>6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Monday</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tuesday</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                            <td>class&Sub</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>WednessDay</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thursday</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Friday</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Friday</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                        <td>class&Sub</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </section>
```

css:

```
@media print {
    section {
        height:25cm;
    }

}
```

jsfiddle :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8u9r4xnb/4/show/

Comment: Actually I want to take a print out of this tables. Print Preview should be having different pages.

Comment: use  jqPrint to print specific table